# linphone-android "Error while using running prepare.py"

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, linphone

I am building linphone-android on Ubuntu 14.04.
According to the the README file, I finish all pre-installation, run the check_tools.sh, and find no problem.

But, then running the prepare.py, I meet the below problem(in cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log):

---

Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/joelly/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3545077747/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3545077747.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3545077747.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/joelly/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/joelly/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3545077747.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/opt/android/ndk/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  -DANDROID -fPIE -isystem /opt/android/ndk/sources/android/cpufeatures -isystem /opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem /opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include -isystem /opt/android/ndk/sources/android/support/include    -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3545077747.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/joelly/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
error: unknown target CPU 'armv5te'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joelly/Downloads/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3545077747.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3545077747/fast] Error 2
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Bravo!
I update my cmake to the newest version , and work it out!